# OK to use lower 32 control ASCII in URI encoded string?

Tags: url, ascii, urlencode

I need a guard character to separate two pieces of information that will be URI encoded together. Is it OK to use one of the lower 32 ASCII control characters? Aside from rendering weird in the browser dev console, will there be any weird unintended effects? Of course, I will avoid commonly used characters like carriage return, tab, and null.

My specific use case: encoding text that is dropped into the browser:

- Optional filename if a file was dropped
- text contents
- URI encoded guard character: '[%12](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0012/index.htm)'

I understand it *is* possible this character might be part of a filename and/or text, but I'm OK with this ambiguity.

Comment: Why not urlencode the contents?

Comment: @MrTux: I am urlencoding the contents. I am concatenating filename + guard character + contents before urlencoding the whole string.

Comment: There is the URI RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986, this issue should already be solved